# How to get tags from the database?

Tags: php, tags

My database structure:

```
News:

id | title |description | slug

Tags:

id | title | slug

Tags news:

id | id tags | id news
```

And the code:

```
$sqltagi = mysql_query("SELECT id_tags FROM tags_news WHERE id_news LIKE '%$id%' ORDER BY id_tagu DESC");

if (!$sqltagi)
{
    echo 'Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltagi);

$lol=$row['id_tagu'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title,slug FROM tags WHERE id LIKE '%$lol%'");
//$sqlq = mysql_fetch_array($sql);


while ($rowid = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
    $aa1=$rowid['title'];
    $aa2=$rowid['slug']; 

    $tags=''.$aa1.' '.$aa2.'';
}
```

how to?

Comment: why first $row is not in a while loop??

Comment: it did not work. I want to show $ tags outside the loop

Comment: I don't understand here your question, what's wrong here and what do you expect ? what did you do that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things! First of all, please don't use `mysql` functions!
 They are not secure, prone to sql injections 
Use `mysqli` or `pdo`, and you should research `joins in sql`.

But if you must use mysql functions, then you can do something like this:

```
<?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT title, slug FROM tags JOIN tags_news ON tags.id = tags_news.id_tags");

    while ($rowid = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $aa1 = $rowid['title'];
        $aa2 = $rowid['slug']; 

        echo $tags = '' . $aa1 . ' ' . $aa2 . '<br />';
    }

?>
```

Comment: I have a question. 

how to display the entry that contains a tag?
domain.com/tag-test.html <-- test or 'slug' tags

slug tags -> ID tags -> 
tags news -> id news ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean! If you want to select the record from the db which contains tags, then try something like this
You have here two tables in your db : [news] id, title, content, tag_id [tags] id, tag
<?php
 // this will get all news that has a tag
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT news.title, news.content, tags.tag FROM news JOIN tags ON tags.id = news.tag_id");
 // loop through all found record
    while ($rowid = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $aa1 = $rowid['title'];
        $aa2 = $rowid['slug']; 
  // display in screen
        echo $tags = '' . $aa1 . ' ' . $aa2 . '<br />';
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
$sqltagi = mysql_query("SELECT id_tags FROM tags_news WHERE id_news LIKE '%$id%' ORDER BY id_tagu DESC");

if (!$sqltagi)
{
    echo 'Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltagi))
{

$lol=$row['id_tags'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title,slug FROM tags WHERE id LIKE '%$lol%'");
//$sqlq = mysql_fetch_array($sql);


    while ($rowid = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
        $aa1=$rowid['title'];
        $aa2=$rowid['slug']; 

        $tags=''.$aa1.' '.$aa2.'';
    }
}
```

Comment: how to display outside the loop? $tags 
shows only one result

Comment: @user3575919 why you want to display outside the loop??? if you want to get all tags than you must loop it..

Comment: Ok. 
whether the above solution is good?
As for optimizing mysql

Comment: for optimizing you should use join queries, so you will need to use only one query... as suggested by christian....